# Static Dropdown populating incorrect value

Tags: c#, html

I have a static dropdown with the following html.

```
    <asp:DropDownList width="100px" ID="dropDownActive"  Runat="server">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Inactive" Value="0"/>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="1" />
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

I try to populate the selected value based off of data, but it has the the value of 0 before I get to it and will not accept a new value.

```
dropDownActive.SelectedValue = (support.Active)? "Active": "Inactive";
```

Comment: When do you try to set its value? At what event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values of your dropdown are "0" and "1", not "Active" and "Inactive"

```
dropDownActive.SelectedValue = (support.Active)? "1": "0";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dropdown list uses 0 & 1 to represent inactive and active values.  So when setting the value, try using those, not their text counterparts.

```
dropDownActive.SelectedValue = (support.Active)? "1": "0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dropDownActive.SelectedValue = (support.Active)? 1: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SelectedValue` property of the ASP DropDownList control is based off of the Value attribute of the markup.

You need to change your code to...

```
dropDownActive.SelectedValue = (support.Active) ? 0 : 1;
```